# Magento 2: How to add different watermark based on Vendor?

Tags: magento2, programmatically, multi-vendor, watermark

I have a multi-vendor setup on my site and based on per vendor products, I want to apply a watermark. By default, Magento applies watermarks on all the products based on the website/ store.
Can anyone tell me how to customize the watermark functionality or point me which file I should extend? I have my custom table from where I want to get the watermark images.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this file /vendor/magento/module-media-storage/Service/ImageResize.php

```
private function getWatermarkFilePath($file)
{
    $path = $this->imageConfig->getMediaPath('/watermark/' . $file);
    return $this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($path);
}
```